# Modify date time string in readable format in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have got this below datetime as string.

2013-12-31T00:00:00+01:00

I would like to show this as

31/12/2013 1am

Please suggest me how can I achieve this using php datetime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because reading the [documentation](http://php.net/datetime) properly would provide the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$old_date = '2013-12-31T00:00:00+01:00';
$new_date = date('d/m/Y Ha',strtotime($old_date));
echo $new_date;
```

This uses Date's ability to convert dates from one format to another

Comment: ahh I was using 'd/m/YHa'...Thanks Ali.

Answer (score 3):

```
$dt = new DateTime('2013-12-31T00:00:00+01:00');
echo $dt->format('d/m/Y Ha');
```

FYI, I voted your question down for showing no effort. This actually is easy to figure out from the docs.

Comment: Thanks John.Actually I tried before with the date() and strtotime but for some reason it was not displaying the correct format that's why I posted here. :)